# Element's clickable area drifted up from actual position on Ipad Safari

Tags: asp.net, ipad, user-interface, safari

I'm having a little problem with my ASP .NET site on Ipad Safari. I have the following form:

- A div overlayed on top of the main form.
- In this div I have an update panel with 4 or 5 drop down lists.
- Each drop down list when changed will pull some data from DB and populate certain gridview on this same div.

On PC using Chrome, FF, IE..., my site works great. But on Ipad Safari, I have this weird problem:

- After user changing a drop down list, there is a chance that the clickable area of all elements will drift upward from the elements's actual position.
- For example, when I click on a button, nothing happens, if I want to use that button, I have to click an empty area a few dozen pixel above it. The same goes for textarea, radio button,...
- The amount which all clickable area drift upward does not seem to be fixed, some time they drift up hundreds of pixels, while other time they only drift up a dozen pixels or so, but all clickable area always drift up by the same amount.
- Zoom in/zoom out on the page or select any textbox will reset all clickable areas to their right positions.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5, and testing on a Ipad using IOS 8.3.  Unfortunately, I can't reproduce it using js and html alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer for this strange issue. Apparently, when I scroll up and down on the overlay div, I might also scroll the main form by accident. If I scroll the main form together with the overlay div, when I click on the drop down list and populate the gridview, all clickable areas on overlay div will drift up. The more I scroll my main form, the more the clickable areas drift.

I fix this issue by adding the following function to onclick event of all drop down list:

```
function fixClickableDrift() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);  
}
```

Now matter how much I scroll my main form, when I click on the drop down lists, this function will reset main form's position back to the top of the page. Hope this will be helpful for someone in the future.